# Modal Component - How to include and open/close from another component

Tags: reactjs

I'm just starting to learn React. I've got a modal component (that's basically a wrapper for react-bootstrap's Modal component). The idea is to have a "Feedback" modal that I can include in various places. This approach isn't working, and I don't know what I don't know :/

Below is a quick example of what I mean / how I'm trying to display my modal component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
import Button from "components/button/button"

export class BaseModal extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { show: false };
    }

    toggleModal() {
        this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.props.show) {
            return null;
        };
        return (
            <>
                <Modal show={this.state.show}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.toggleModal}>
                            Close
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.toggleModal}>
                            Save Changes
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

A simple page like this - clicking this button doesn't do anything (React dev tools show no BaseModal node in the vdom)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Button from "components/button/button"
import BaseModal from "components/modals/baseModal"

export class ButtonDocs extends Component {
    render() {
        <Button value="Open Modal" onClick={BaseModal.toggleModal} />
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just import a `Component` and then call a method on it, because you aren't actually rendering it anywhere.

What you need to do is render the Component, and then if you want to control the state of one component from another you need to "lift state up" and pass the state and any methods needed to the modal component as props.  Something like this:

Modal Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
import Button from "components/button/button"

export class BaseModal extends Component {

    render() {
        if (!this.props.show) {
            return null;
        };
        return (
            <>
                <Modal show={this.state.show}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.props.toggleModal}>
                            Close
                        </Button>
                        <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.props.toggleModal}>
                            Save Changes
                        </Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Button Docs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Button from "components/button/button"
import BaseModal from "components/modals/baseModal"

export class ButtonDocs extends Component {

constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { show: false };
    }

    toggleModal() {
        this.setState({ show: !this.state.show })
    }

    render() {
        <Button value="Open Modal" onClick={this.toggleModal} />
        <BaseModal show={this.state.show} toggleModal={this.toggleModal} />
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, aright. So `lifting state up` really means that the state of a descendent component is manipulated by (and passed to / updated by) the ancestral component, by calling methods of the ancestor that cause a re-rendering of the imported descendent. I guess this is making sense - just a whole new way of thinking! Thank you!

Comment: Exactly.  Sounds like you are getting the hang of it!

Comment: Really make sense, just a modification @TravisJames, in BaseModal class the `show={this.state.show}` should be `show={this.props.show}`. It Worked for me Thank you